# Multitude of C++ objects from permutations on finite set of base classes

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, particle-system

I am developing a kind of theoretical particle system that creates compound particles (objects) from basic building blocks (classes). To illustrate, consider the following set of classes:

```
class A; class B; class C; .... class Z;
```

That form the building blocks for compound particles. A compound particle is defined as:

```
class C1C2...CN : public C1C2...C(N-1)
```

For example,

```
class AZB : public AZ, public B {};
class AZ : public A, public Z {};
```

One constraint is that classes constructed in different order are not equivalent. In other words:

```
ABZ != AZB != BAZ != BZA != ZAB != ZBA
```

Now this system can produce a huge number of possible objects. For N base classes the total number of possible permutations is approximately **N(N!) - 1! -2! - ... -(N-1)!**. Note: it is much, much larger than **N!**

So the two immediately obvious hurdles I'm facing are

1. there are too many permutations to be written by hand
2. as far as I know C++ does not allow runtime class creation, so automation at runtime goes out the window.

Any helpful pointers about how I could automate this would be appreciated!

Comment: Here's a question that is possibly too obvious: why do you want different classes for each of these? Why not use, say, a vector to represent a compound particle?

Comment: I didn't want to make this question too long to explain the problem in totality.  In short, when combining classes functions are overloaded. for example the operator **+** has to have a different meaning for  `ABZ + AZB` than for `ABZ + ZBA`. That also, I realize, has be automated somehow. how would that be accomplished... one step at a time i guess :)

Comment: In what way do the operators differ? I doubt that the best approach for this will turn out to be one-class-per-particle.

Comment: See: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/131139)

Comment: Yes, you are right, C++ does not create classes at run time, and there are too many of them to be pre-generated. So perhaps having compound particles represented by inheritance is not a feasible idea.

Comment: *Prefer composition over inheritance.* Just search for that on Google and read the first few links.

Comment: as you noticed c++ does not allow runtime class creation, so you either have to devise your own pseudo-class objects that mimic the behaviour you want and which you will be able to create at runtime OR you will have to resort to template meta-programing tricks to do what you want at compile-time.

Comment: The modelling as class is wrong. The math appears to be wrong. With N kinds of atoms and K atoms in a string where order matters, you have simply N^K possible strings.

Comment: jtbandes, n.m., you could be right. Daniel Jour, thanks for the pointer, it might be very helpful. Marinos K, both suggestions are beyond my skills at the moment, but they might be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf you're misreading the problem. no class inherits a base class twice. in this way it becomes a permutation. objects can are made from different number of base classes, with the upper bound being the number of different base classes, and lower bound 1 (which is that base class itself). In that way it becomes a sum of permutations.

Comment: That's fine, but it still doesn't require the use of classes in this way. Trying to encode all this in the C++ template/type system may be possible, but probably isn't worth it when you could just use an array/vector. Since you have not actually specified any requirements of what these objects do, it's impossible to suggest anything more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too many details, it sounds like composition is the way to go (as opposed to inheritance).

Create multiple particle classes all inheriting from the same base class:

```
class Particle;

class A : public Particle; ...; class Z : public Particle;
```

Then create a a particle composition class that contains a vector of particle pointers:

```
class ParticleComposition
{
    private:
        vector<Particle*> m_particles;
};
```

If need be, you could also have a vector of ParticleComposition pointers in ParticleComposition:

```
class ParticleComposition
{
    private:
        vector<Particle*> m_particles;
        vector<ParticleCompositon*> m_compositons;
};
```

Now any function in ParticleComposition can be dependent on the ordering of your particles (via a runtime check). It might also be useful to include a virtual function in your particle class, that returns the type of particle:

```
enum particleType{BASE, A, B, Z}; //and so on

class Particle
{
    public:
        virtual particleType getType(){return BASE;}
};

class A : public Particle
{
    public:
        virtual particleType getType(){return A;}
};
```

If you want to you can create a similar function for your ParticleComposition class that returns a number dependent on the ordering of its particles.

Now all your order dependent code can be determined at runtime.